# power bi hierarchy select layer l-1

Tags: powerbi, selection, hierarchy

I'm currently working with power bi and wanted to filter a factory production site

**The site**, which is itself divided into **zones** themselves divided into **lines** create the hierarchy I have in power bi. *ref left of the exemple*

On a **Pie chart**, I'd like to visualize the distribution of values attributed to thoses locations but only to the **next layer** of the hierarchy. *ref right of the exemple*

**Exemple:**

[image: exemple:]

As you can see, selecting S only shows me the next layer of values ie. Z1 and Z2

When selecting Z1 I then have the three lines (L1, L2, L3)

**tests I've made so far:**

Best I've found is duplicating the hierarchy table and linking the values to there parent ids. So when filtering an element, values connected to it don't show up.

I also tried different approches to hide the deep layers, but can't figure a way to do it, any ideas how to?

**update 2 days after posted:**

It's been 2 days since I posted and I continued doing some tests, I thought I had a solution by doing a great-parent table of the hierarchy. I would then only have to substract the great-child to childs to have the data I wanted, unfortunatly I couldn't figure it out.

I also tried creating a copy of the table, filtered while created but it doesn't seem to affect the output.

I tried doing some magic with ids but same problem, couldn't find a way to achieve the problem.

**Here are my tests data:**

hierarchy:

| Id | Name | parentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Site |  |
| 2 | Zone1 | 1 |
| 3 | Zone2 | 1 |
| 4 | Line1 | 2 |
| 5 | Line2 | 2 |
| 6 | Line3 | 3 |
| 7 | Line4 | 3 |

Sensor:

| Id | Name | hierarchyId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Total site | 1 |
| 2 | Total zone1 | 2 |
| 3 | Total zone2 | 3 |
| 4 | Line1 | 4 |
| 5 | Line2 | 4 |
| 6 | Line3 | 5 |
| 7 | Line4 | 6 |

mesures:

| SensorId | Name | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 240 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 2 | 140 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 3 | 100 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 4 | 70 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 5 | 20 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 6 | 50 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 7 | 100 | 21/06/2022 10:21:10.000 |
| 1 | 260 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 2 | 150 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 3 | 110 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 4 | 80 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 5 | 20 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 6 | 50 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 7 | 110 | 21/06/2022 10:31:10.000 |
| 1 | 260 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 2 | 160 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 3 | 100 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 4 | 80 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 5 | 20 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 6 | 60 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |
| 7 | 100 | 21/06/2022 10:41:10.000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I solved the problem is with a semi-automated solution.

**Defining each layer in calculated columns:**

[image]

**diging down the chart with the multiple columns as filters:**

[image]

It is not fully automated but still do the job. If you have a better solution I'll be happy to see it :)